# How to call ruby class from Groovy class and execute it from groovy class

Tags: ruby, groovy

I wrote a ruby class which has print statement. Then i wrote a Groovy class which invokes this ruby class and executes

I tried like Process.execute("ruby.exe test.rb")

Ruby code-->

```
class Test
  puts "hello, I am ruby" 
end
```

Groovy code-->

```
class TestGroovy {

    static main(String[] args) {
        Process.execute("ruby.exe test.rb")
    }

}
```

i need to get output as hello, I am ruby when i run TestGroovy.

Comment: there is a lot of answered questions about executing command line from groovy. just search...

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#process-management):

> Groovy provides a simple way to execute command line processes. Simply write the command line as a string and call the execute() method. E.g., on a *nix machine (or a windows machine with appropriate *nix commands installed), you can execute this:
>
> ```
> def process = "ls -l".execute()      // <1>
> println "Found text ${process.text}" // <2>
> ```
>
> 1. executes the ls command in an external process
> 2. consume the output of the command and retrieve the tex

Answer (score 0):

You can execute Ruby code from Groovy or Java code using a JSR-223 script engine.  Here is an example Groovy script:

```
@Grab('org.jruby:jruby:9.2.5.0')
import javax.script.ScriptEngine
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName('jruby')

engine.eval('puts "Hello world!"')
```

`eval()` also accepts a `java.io.Reader` which you could get from your file path.  There are lots more details on ways to run Ruby from Java/Groovy here: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/RedBridge